# sql running total math current quarter

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to figure out the total for the quarter when the only data shown is a running total for the year:

```
Id      Amount      Periods     Year        Type        Date
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       65          2           2014        G           4-1-12
2       75          3           2014        G           7-1-12
3       25          1           2014        G           1-1-12
4       60          1           2014        H           1-1-12
5       75          1           2014        Y           1-1-12
6       120         3           2014        I           7-1-12
7       30          1           2014        I           1-1-12
8       90          2           2014        I           4-1-12
```

In the data shown above. The items in type G and I are running totals for the period (in qtrs). If my query returns period 3, is there a sql way to get the data for the qtr? The math would involve retrieving the data for the 3rd period - 2nd period.

Right now my sql is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE Date='4-1-12';
```

In this query, it will return row #1, which is a total for 2 periods. I would like it to return just the total for the 2nd period. Im looking to make this happen with SQLite.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to subtract the running total of the previous quarter:

```
SELECT Id,
       Year,
       Type,
       Date,
       Amount - IFNULL((SELECT Amount
                        FROM data AS previousQuarter
                        WHERE previousQuarter.Year = data.year
                          AND previousQuarter.Type = data.Type
                          AND previousQuarter.Periods = data.Periods - 1
                       ), 0) AS Amount
FROM data
```

The IFNULL is needed to handle a quarter that has no previous quarter.